# Apo Address Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I tried to create a Regular expression. To validate a city that must start with "apo" or "fpo".

Without or with space and dot in between "a.p.o" or "Apo", "APO". I tried this:

```
^(APO)?|(apo)?\s*\.\w
```

but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# .NET

Use [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23.aspx) with [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx). The regex:

```
@"^[af][ .]?p[ .]?o"
```

Objective-C

You can use `- (NSTextCheckingResult *)firstMatchInString:(NSString *)string options:(NSMatchingOptions)options range:(NSRange)range` method to check for the first match. If not found then failure. The regex:

```
@"^(?i)[af][ .]?p[ .]?o"
```

Comment: thanks a lot after putting this it will not validating the input i can put any character instead what i want to vALIDATE IS the CITY must start with APO Prefix

Comment: @amit: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. The regex should work, as seen here (ruby and Obj-C regex at least support the features I used in the regex): http://rubular.com/r/oz9dEqziKj

Comment: @amit: You are using C#? Or Obj-C?

Comment: C# asp.net i got aspx where i have put this regular expression

Comment: @amitmishra: I don't know about ASP.NET, but shouldn't there be someway to quote some sort of code? Or are you referring to client-side Javascript validation?

Comment: its done i got an idea to use some javascript function to substring the first three character and validate it at client side thanks nhahtdh you rocks